# Water to Air Geothermal without Heat Pump

Tags: hvac

I need about one ton of heating / cooling for a 6x10 green house. Is there a way to use buried piping and water to air without a Heat Pump?

My theory is based on the following:

- Location: SE Georgia
- 6x10 Green house 3/16" Polycarbonate
- 12000 BTU Loss/Gain ?
- Keep from freezing in winter and assist with cooling in summer.
- My backhoe will dig up to 8 ft deep
- I assume ground temperature to be 50 degrees F
- Minimum air temp 20F  Max 100F
- Bury 500 feet 3/4" plastic pipe at 8 ft and 6 ft
- Circulate water/glycol through auto radiator with fan behind it
- Control pump and fan with thermostat.

What am I missing?

Comment: Cooling maybe since the water should be around a constant 50 to 60 degrees.  Solar water heating might work without a heat pump.  Either way would need a radiator and fan, only need a couple more parts to have a heat pump(simplistic view)

Comment: Needs more info: what outdoor soil and indoor air temperature design conditions are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I live in Southeast Georgia near the coast . Coldest id 20  F overnight. Hottest is 100 . I have thought about using the air to air tube system but I;m concerned about water table. There for it makes sense to use water to air. I'm assuming 50 F ground temp at 4 to 6 ft deep.  Heating cooling assumptions 12000 btu . Unknown how much piping I would need . Radiator size ?

Answer (score 1):

Heat only travels from hot to cold. The magic of heat pumps and air conditioners is moving heat from cold to hot. So if you want air that is close to underground temps, this can work.  Most likely, you can do this for heating or cooling, but not both.

There are definitely people who use a geothermal loop for cooling, you just need to pay to run the pump and fan.  50-55 degree (F) (or whatever the constant ground temp is where you live) water can be used for cooling but it won't dehumidify like an AC unit will, though your plants probably don't care.  50-55 degree (F) water will be difficult to use for heating unless you just want to keep things from freezing.  Certainly you could never get hotter than about 50 degrees.

Not sure how accurate [this guy](https://youtu.be/nV7XJXETr0Q?si=ZLKKWFqxX4QzKTiD) is but he's after the same thing you are.  I know I've seen a video by a guy who uses geothermal water for cooling with a unit from a reefer trailer for backup.  Lots of similar videos are out there.

Comment: Thank you good information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. ;^)

If you have an elevated natural spring to move the water, and a pipe run low to heat with and a pipe run high to cool with, that might be a passive system with no heat pump.

For coils buried in the ground, a simple circulating pump is arguably acting as a heat pump, and so is a fan on the air coil side, if used. Not the refrigerant-based one you are thinking of when you say heat pump, but you're still applying power to move heat around, it's just that the heat you are moving around is (typically, depending where and how deep your coils are buried) always around 50°F/10°C plus or minus a few degrees.

One trick you'll have to master is having enough area on both the buried coil and the air coil to move enough heat to keep your greenhouse warm or cool with that limited temperature fluid. You might need (wild guesstimate, zero calculations performed) 3-5 times the coil area that a system using a more active heat pump and generating higher/lower coil temperatures would need.

Answer (score 0):

If you live on top of hot springs or hot rock, then you could pump hot water through buried pipes and around a radiator.  If you particularly want a warm air system, then put a fan behind the radiator.

Otherwise, the air that blows out of your system will be no warmer than the rocks that are feeding your system.  So you may be able to get your greenhouse above freezing that way, but it won't actually get warm.

Comment: It's a greenhouse. Generally the ground temperature (if fully conveyed to the greenhouse, which will be the trick) is entirely adequate as heating temperatures go - not freezing to 10°C/50°F being typical range for anything but a full on tropical conservatory when heating one.